# Are ASMX Web Service Enable Session and ResponseFormat Required

Tags: asp.net, json, web-services

I have been asked to change a legacy `.asmx` web service and there are a few issues I would appreciate some guidance on.

The web methods are decorated like this:

```
  [WebMethod(EnableSession = true), ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
```

In my particular method, I am returning data from a database, which I return as a list of to  of objects using `JSON`.

I noticed that the `JSON` is still returned without the: `ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json` part.

In that case:

- can I safely remove this from here?
- if it still works, does that mean it will be configured elsewhere in a base class or config file perhaps?
- What is the purpose of the `(EnableSession = true)` and is it required if the service does not update the data and the read data is rarely changed?

Sorry for the basic rather vague questions but I've not worked with .asmx web services before.  Can someone point me in the right direction please?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AS @Karl already said if you need to access Session in webmethod, you've to decorate your method with the said attribute.

Now I've seen people complaining about webmethod not returning JSON response on SO and Asp.net official forum  even though they have decorated their method with

```
ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)
```

because they might have missing configuration in web.config.

I would suggest you to go through Dave Ward's below articles that may help you to understand what needs to be done to return JSON response with ASMX:

[ASMX and JSON – Common mistakes and misconceptions](http://encosia.com/asmx-and-json-common-mistakes-and-misconceptions/)

[ASMX ScriptService mistake: Installation and configuration](http://encosia.com/asmx-scriptservice-mistakes-installation-and-configuration/)

Answer (score 2):

`EnableSession = true` allows you to access the `Session` collection, which is part of the `HttpContext.Current.Session`. If the code in your web method does not use the `Session` collection, then yes it is safe to remove, but if it does use the `Session` collection, then removing this attribute will cause your web service logic to throw an exception, because it will not have access to the `Session` collection.

`ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)` is explicitly defining that this web method will return `JSON`, but since `JSON` is the default return type, then removing it does not matter. So the short answer is, yes it is fine to remove this, but it will not hurt to leave it there (in fact I would argue that is better to because it explicitly states this thing is returning `JSON` data).

Comment: thanks.  forgive me, why is JSON the default return type?  Is it 'out of the box' or configure somewhere else?

Comment: Out-of-the-box, the configuration is done through the attribute. For instance if your web service method used the `XmlDocument` object, then you would want to change your response format to XML, like this: `ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Xml)`.

Comment: You should read the [MSDN documentation for the ScriptMethod attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.services.scriptmethodattribute.aspx)